# Downsample array in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, gdal

I have basic 2-D numpy arrays and I'd like to "downsample" them to a more coarse resolution.  Is there a simple numpy or scipy module that can easily do this?  I should also note that this array is being displayed geographically via Basemap modules.

SAMPLE:
[image]

Answer (score 14):

`scikit-image` has implemented a working version of `downsampling` here, although they shy away from calling it `downsampling` for it not being a downsampling in terms of DSP, if I understand correctly:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce

but it works very well, and it is the only `downsampler` that I found in Python that can deal with `np.nan` in the image. I have downsampled gigantic images with this very quickly.

Answer (score 13):

When downsampling, interpolation is the wrong thing to do. Always use an aggregated approach.

I use block means to do this, using a "factor" to reduce the resolution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

def block_mean(ar, fact):
    assert isinstance(fact, int), type(fact)
    sx, sy = ar.shape
    X, Y = np.ogrid[0:sx, 0:sy]
    regions = sy//fact * (X//fact) + Y//fact
    res = ndimage.mean(ar, labels=regions, index=np.arange(regions.max() + 1))
    res.shape = (sx//fact, sy//fact)
    return res
```

E.g., a (100, 200) shape array using a factor of 5 (5x5 blocks) results in a (20, 40) array result:

```
ar = np.random.rand(20000).reshape((100, 200))
block_mean(ar, 5).shape  # (20, 40)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  I think your solution is more of what I am looking for.  When applying your code, I am getting an error due to mismatch of array size: 
`File "diffplot.py", line 38, in block_mean
    res.shape = (sx/fact, sy/fact)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Comment: The problem above was due to the need for the factor to be equally divisible into the original array shape.  However, this function still provides the improper results.  Interesting. Does not seem to be 're-sampling' like what I am looking for. Instead, it took the diff array and plotted it multiple times in the basemap window. I think I need some sort of an aggregation or dissolve technique. Thanks for your input thus far.

Comment: Hi Mike, would you mind explaining why interpolation is a bad way to downsample? If interpolating is bad, is there a nice way of dealing with cases where the image dimensions aren't divisible by the desired block size?

Comment: This is an alternative implementation of the same thing, I believe: https://github.com/keflavich/image_registration/blob/master/image_registration/fft_tools/downsample.py#L11.  I'm not sure how the speed compares, but I'd bet scipy.ndimage is a bit faster.

Comment: does not work: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Answer (score 6):

[imresize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) and [ndimage.interpolation.zoom](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom) look like they do what you want

I haven't tried imresize before but here is how I have used ndimage.interpolation.zoom

```
a = np.array(64).reshape(8,8)
a = ndimage.interpolation.zoom(a,.5) #decimate resolution
```

a is then a 4x4 matrix with interpolated values in it

Comment: Here is a code snippet:

`findiff = scipy.misc.imresize(diff, 30., interp='bilinear', mode=None)
frefcobj = m.pcolormesh(x,y,findiff,shading='flat',vmin=-15,vmax=15,cmap=cmap,zorder=1)
colbar = m.colorbar(frefcobj,"bottom",size="4%",pad="5%",extend='both',ticks=intervals)`

diff is a 699x699 array. 

Does not seem to be achieving the task.

Comment: I haven't tried imresize before, but I added a snippet using zoom.  Is that not what you are looking for?  I can't test imresize at the moment because I have an older version of scipy which doesn't seem to include it

Comment: Interesting.  Does not seem to be 're-sampling' like what I am looking for.  Instead, it took the diff array and plotted it multiple times in the basemap window.  I think I need some sort of an aggregation or dissolve technique.  Thanks for your input thus far.

Comment: By downsample you mean you want fewer samples than when you started right?  Or do you mean you want to blur your matrix?

Comment: I'd like to make the new array more "coarse," so fewer samples.

Comment: Interpolation should *never* be used to downsample anything.

Comment: imresize is int8 precision, and ndimage.interpolation.zoom uses nearest-neighbor downsampling. Both are not very helpful for numerical data.

Comment: This function has been [removed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.3.0.html?highlight=imresize#scipy-interpolate-changes) from `scipy`.

Answer (score 5):

*Easiest way*:
You can use the `array[0::2]` notation, which only considers every second index.
E.g.

```py
array= np.array([[i+j for i in range(0,10)] for j in range(0,10)])
down_sampled=array[0::2,0::2]

print("array \n", array)
print("array2 \n",down_sampled)
```

has the output:

```
array 
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
 [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]]
array2 
[[ 0  2  4  6  8]
 [ 2  4  6  8 10]
 [ 4  6  8 10 12]
 [ 6  8 10 12 14]
 [ 8 10 12 14 16]]
```

Comment: you can also use `[::2]`

Answer (score 4):

xarray's "coarsen" method can downsample a xarray.Dataset or xarray.DataArray

- http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.coarsen.html
- http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#coarsen-large-arrays

For example:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15,5))

# Create a 10x10 array of random numbers
a = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(10,10)*100, dims=['x', 'y'])

# "Downscale" the array, mean of blocks of size (2x2)
b = a.coarsen(x=2, y=2).mean()

# "Downscale" the array, mean of blocks of size (5x5)
c = a.coarsen(x=5, y=5).mean()


# Plot and cosmetics
a.plot(ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("Full Data")

b.plot(ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("mean of (2x2) boxes")

c.plot(ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title("mean of (5x5) boxes")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Because the OP just wants a courser resolution, I thought I would share my way for reducing number of pixels by half in each dimension. I takes the mean of 2x2 blocks. This can be applied multiple times to reduce by factors of 2.

```
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
array_downsampled = convolve(array, 
                 np.array([[0.25,0.25],[0.25,0.25]]))[:array.shape[0]:2,:array.shape[1]:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you're looking for, but I thought I'd mention it for completeness.

You could try installing `scikits.samplerate` ([docs](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/samplerate/sphinx/overview.html)), which is a Python wrapper for libsamplerate. It provides nice, high-quality resampling algorithms -- BUT as far as I can tell, it only works in 1D. You might be able to resample your 2D signal first along one axis and then along another, but I'd think that might counteract the benefits of high-quality resampling to begin with.

Comment: Yes, that won't work for this situation, but thanks for the input.  I need something that can aggregate spatially.

Answer (score 1):

This will take an image of any resolution and return only a quarter of its size by taking the 4th index of the image array.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def quarter_res_drop(im):

    resized_image = im[0::4, 0::4]
    cv2.imwrite('resize_result_image.png', resized_image)

    return resized_image

im = cv2.imread('Your_test_image.png', 1)

quarter_res_drop(im)
```